# Low power method to turn Raspberry Pi on or off using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, relay, raspberry-pi, opto-isolator

I want to use an Arduino to control power to a Raspberry Pi.

The power supply to this system is a solar panel with rechargeable cells, and the Arduino will turn the Pi off to preserve power in darkness or when the cells are running low.

So, I'd like to be able to switch the power as efficiently as possible.

What are my options? How much power might I lose with a suitable relay? I thought an optocoupler might be one way, but can I use one to switch around 500mA?

Comment: An Arduino *and* a Raspberry Pi? Ardpino?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the arduino isn't particularly power-efficient either. If you want decent power efficiency, you're going to probably have to roll your own ATmega based controller.

Comment: I know, but I have one and it draws a lot less than the Pi. If I get this working I can do something like this to make a more efficient Arduino clone http://hwstartup.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/how-to-run-an-arduino-on-a-9v-battery-for-weeks-or-months/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small 5V latching relay will do it. As it latches, it consumes no power except when changing state.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go, thanks. Is it possible to sense the current state of a latching relay?

Comment: Since you're only switching 5V just connect the switched side to a digital in. The ones I've used have two coils so mostly you don't need to know the state, just put it into the state you want.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bitwizard.nl/wiki/index.php?title=Reducing_power_consumption_of_a_raspberry_Pi

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/how-do-i-supply-power-through-the-gpio

Alternative slightly more complicated approach: remove the 3.3V linear regulator, or isolate it by cutting tracks. Replace it with a suitable buck converter which has a "shutdown" or "enable" pin.